# Baofeng DM-1801 DMR: Language switched to Chinese

Tags: baofeng

The screen reset to Chinese characters. How do I get it back to English? I haven’t found any information on this problem.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [manual](https://fccid.io/2AJGM-DM1801/User-Manual/User-manual-4125309):

This radio supports both Chinese and English language. The menu functions as follows:

1. Press [MENU] to enter menu mode.
2. Press [ ]/ [ ] to set, then press [MENU] to select.
3. Press [ ]/ [ ] to the radio setting, then press [MENU] to select.
4. Press [ ]/ [ ] to language selection, then press [MENU] to select.
5. Press [ ]/ [ ] to select the corresponding language, then press [MENU] to select.
6. The screen shows the language selected and returns to the main screen.

Answer (score 1):

Press [MENU] to enter menu mode.

Select the wrench, then press [MENU] to select.

Select 1, then press [MENU] to select.

Should come up on a 2 character selection that is not selected, then press [MENU] to select.

The screen shows the language selected and returns to the main screen.

Answer (score 1):

Select the wrench, then press [MENU] to select.

Select 1, then press [MENU] to select.
Select 17, then press [MENU] to select.
Then select English, then press [MENU] to select.